# Necessito separar uma mensagem String em 6 TextViews

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um app com conexão bluetooth e ele captura as mensagens ou dados que são enviados pelo arduino via Bluetooth, estou enviando essas mensagens via Bluetooth, a cada chamada envia um dado e cada dado deveria ser mostrado no seu Textview específico, então como faço para direcionar esse dado para seu TextView específico?
A troca de informações já acontece só que o único dado é enviado e aparece em todos os Textview não aparece em apenas um, e gostaria que fosse as informações separadas por exemplo temperatura em um e humidade em outro.

```
   /*
    * Função que envia a mensagem do celular para o módulo Bluetooth, exibindo no monitor serial.
    */
    private void enviar(String str) {
        if(connected != Connected.True) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Não conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            String msg;
            byte[] data;
                msg = str;
                data = (str + newline).getBytes();
            SpannableStringBuilder spn = new SpannableStringBuilder(msg+'\n');
            spn.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSendText)), 0, spn.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            receiveText.append(spn);
            service.write(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            onSerialIoError(e);
        }
    }

    //Envia a mensagem para o receptor, ou seja, o celular... do arduino para o celular
    private void receptor(byte[] data) {
            String msg = new String(data);

            /*
            if(newline.equals(newline_crlf) && msg.length() > 0) {
                // não mostra CRLF como ^M se diretamente antes de LF
                msg = msg.replace(newline_crlf, newline_lf);
                // tratamento especial se CRLF e LF vierem em fragmentos separados
                if (pendingNewline && msg.charAt(0) == '\n') {
                    Editable edt = receiveText.getEditableText();
                    if (edt != null && edt.length() > 1)
                        edt.replace(edt.length() - 2, edt.length(), "");
                }
                pendingNewline = msg.charAt(msg.length() - 1) == '\r';
            }*/

        humidadeSolo.append(TextUtil.toCaretString(msg, newline.length() != 0));
        receiveText.append(TextUtil.toCaretString(msg, newline.length() != 0));
        
        }
```

Este outro Trecho de código trata a informação recebida para ser exibida no Textview, mais qual tratamento eu deveria empregar para fragmentar essa mensagem em duas partes ou mais e eu destina-la para seus TextViews respectivos, Me ajudem por favor...

```
 static CharSequence toCaretString(CharSequence s, boolean keepNewline) {
        return toCaretString(s, keepNewline, s.length());
    }

    static CharSequence toCaretString(CharSequence s, boolean keepNewline, int length) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < length; pos++) {
            if (s.charAt(pos) < 32 && (!keepNewline ||s.charAt(pos)!='\n')) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
            return s;
        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        for(int pos=0; pos<length; pos++)
            if (s.charAt(pos) < 32 && (!keepNewline ||s.charAt(pos)!='\n')) {
                sb.append('^');
                sb.append((char)(s.charAt(pos) + 64));
                sb.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(caretBackground), sb.length()-2, sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            } else {
                sb.append(s.charAt(pos));
            }
        return sb;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dica: Veja a [**documentação**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) sobre TextViews

Para definir textos específicos para TextViews distintos voce precisa primeiro definir o id (@+id) de cada um, em seguida, use o método desejado apontando para o id correto.

Comment: Pronto estou tentando fazer isso, mais a minha dúvida mesmo é como que eu vou separar essa String sem dar erros?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando:

```js
/*
 *Abordagem utilizando split.
 */
String[] speed = dataString.split("@");
temperatura.setText("");
temperatura.append(speed[0]);
umidadeAr.setText("");
umidadeAr.append(speed[1]);
altitude.setText("");
altitude.append(speed[2]);
pressao.setText("");
pressao.append(speed[3]);
velVento.setText("");
velVento.append(speed[4]);
chuva.setText("");
chuva.append(speed[5]);
umiSolo.setText("");
umiSolo.append(speed[6]);
qualiAr.setText("");
qualiAr.append(speed[7]);
```

/*
*Abordagem utilizando split.
*/
String[] speed = dataString.split("@");
temperatura.setText("");
temperatura.append(speed[0]);
umidadeAr.setText("");
umidadeAr.append(speed[1]);
altitude.setText("");
altitude.append(speed[2]);
pressao.setText("");
pressao.append(speed[3]);
velVento.setText("");
velVento.append(speed[4]);
chuva.setText("");
chuva.append(speed[5]);
umiSolo.setText("");
umiSolo.append(speed[6]);
qualiAr.setText("");
qualiAr.append(speed[7]);